# API Calls in Laravel Repository Model

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5, repository-pattern

I am developing a web application in which I will be using third party API integrations (Payment gateways, SMS Vendors, Emailing services like mailchimp, other external APIs). My application will be having the repository pattern which will have repositories associated with each of my models and my controllers will be utilising the repository functions.

Now where does all my API integrations comes in? Should I be keeping all my API integrations in a single repository?

Example :

If I have a SMS provider Valuefirst, how does my Laravel repository design look like?

### My SMS interface

```
interface ISmsProvider {
    public function sendSms($mobileNo,$msg);
}
```

### My ValueFirst (SMS Provider) repository

```
class ValueFirstRepository implements ISmsProvider {
    public function sendSMS($mobieNo,$msg)
    {
       //API Call to ValueFirst SMS provider
       // Any database insertions/updates to SMS model
       // Any file logs
    }
}
```

Assuming I have a service provider class where I have done the binding of the interface and repository my controller will look like

### SMS Controller

```
class SmsController extends BaseController {
    // ISmsProvider is the interface
    public function __construct(ISmsProvider $sms)
    {
        $this->sms = $sms;
    }

    public function sendSMS()
    {
        $mobileNo = '9999999999';
        $msg = 'Hello World!';
        $users = $this->sms->sendSMS($mobileNo,$msg); 
    }    
}
```

My questions

1. Is this the right approach to an API integration using repository pattern?
2. Does anything related to any database activities happens in the ValueFirst repository? Eg : If I want to update a record after the API response from ValueFirst, do I do it in the repository?
3. If it's right , can someone show me how the model interactions happens from the repository?
4. Now if I need to choose between ValueFirst or any other vendor how does that happens? How can I do it from the controller?

I will be using this project as a skeleton for my application

[l5-Repository](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository)

Please help me with this design, I am fairly new to Laravel / repository pattern. Trying to learn stuff. TIA :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach seems pretty good to me but there is something i would improve

First of all I would keep the `ValueFirstRepository` class with the only resposability of managing your SMS API, and inject a specific repository class ( `SmsRepository` ) to interact with the DB through eloquent ( or only a model if you don't need a repository )

The important point here is to keep the resposability of managing your API in one class and the responsability of interacting with the DB in another:

**ValueFirstRepository**

```
class ValueFirstRepository implements ISmsProvider 
{
    //INJECT REPOSITORY CLASS TO INTERACT WITH DB
    public function __construct(SmsRepository $smsRepo )
    {
        $this->smsRepo = $smsRepo;    
    }

    //this method will be called from your controller
    public function sendSMS($mobieNo,$msg)
    {
       //API CALL
        $info = this->sendSMSAPI($mobieNo,$msg);

       //DB CALL
        $this->smsRepo->save( $info );

       // Any file logs
    }

    //this will actually interact with the API
    protected function sendSMSAPI($mobieNo,$msg)
    {
       //API Call to ValueFirst SMS provider
    }

}
```

A litte variant to this solution could be using events, and fire events in your `ValueFirstRepository` class when a sms is sent, and respond to that event implementing some listeners that will do other operations related to the event

Another alternative solution could be to handle the steps directly in your controller:

**SMS Controller**

```
//INJECT THE DEPENDECIES IN YOUR CONTROLLER
public function __construct(ISmsProvider $sms, SmsRepository $smsRepo )
{
    $this->sms = $sms;
    $this->smsRepo = $smsRepo;
}

public function sendSMS()
{
    //send SMS
    $mobileNo = '9999999999';
    $msg = 'Hello World!';
    $info= $this->sms->sendSMS($mobileNo,$msg);

    //use the model to save data
    this->$smsRepo->save($info); 
}
```

This time the dependency of `SmsRepository` would be injected in the controller, instead of the `ValueFirstRepository` class, and the controller's methods would be a litte more big, but it's up to you to decide the best way for you

For the last question: if you want to change your vendor provider, you could use Laravel's capability to [bind interfaces to implementation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations) through the `bind` method:

```
App::bind( App\ISmsProvider::class , App\ValueFirstRepository::class );
```

This will tell laravel wich class inject when requesting a specific interface. So, in this case, when a `ISmsProvider` interface is requested, Laravel will automatically inject a `ValueFirstRepository` concrete instance.

If you want to change the vendor you should only change the line to:

```
App::bind( App\ISmsProvider::class , App\AnotherSMSVendorRepository::class );
```

and the `AnotherSMSVendorRepository` class will be injected instead of `ValueFirstRepository`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Also I would like to know where does Services come to picture in between this flow? Apart from repository,interface where does services come to picture. Can you just give me an idea of a use case in the above example?

Comment: @user34305 : Take the `ValueFirstRepository` class: we could have named it a 'service' instead of 'repository' because it's a service class used to interact with the SMS API. The word 'repository' is more used to indicate an abstraction layer over the DB. In fact a good place to make the `App::bind` calls would be a Service Provider providing the binding for the sms service class

Comment: So is it just the class name which has to be changed ?

Comment: If you want, you don't need to change anything: it's only a naming convention. The important thing is to understand what is the difference between a service and a repository

Comment: so it is just the naming convention. Services refers to external services which the laravel app will be consuming and repository is an abstraction layer to the native DB, if i am not wrong?

Comment: a service could be also a Laravel internal service class: a class for handle DB connection, a class for a Logger etc.. almost any class that you register through a [Service Provider](http://laravel.com/docs/master/providers)

Comment: But how can I differentiate between both of them? Is it just the naming convention which is used? Or is there any special situations where you will have to use services and situations where you have to use repository?

Comment: They are two different concepts: a Repository is a design in witch you use a class to make an abstraction layer over the DB (in our case the sms db entities) a Service is a broad term, and it includes almost any type of service class of your application. If you want to find more search on google examples of Services and repositories in Laravel and check how they are used

Comment: Thanks Moppo for answering all the queries